# What is the best view to decide a run out?

Tags: cricket, officiating

In cricket, what's the best angle to view if a batsman is out or not out in a run out scenario?
Is it from an angle where the umpire runs to (so on the sides) or is it from the bowlers' end?

Answer (score 2):

When judging  a run out the best position is viewed as being level with the popping crease and in position to see the wickets being broken as well, at the end the ball is being thrown.

Now lots of umpires including me suggest that at times a better view is gained by being at a 45 degree angle with the batsmen running towards you and the line.  This is best used when you don't have time to get to the square position.

An important factor in position is that the human eyes have poor image stabalisation and so you will always be best standing eyes still and level to make the decision